# Sorting a linked list of names alphabetically

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Hey guys I am trying to sort a linked list alphabetically by multiplying the first 3 letters together.  The way it works is that the first letter would take 26^2, the second letter would be 26^1 and the third would be 26^0.  When i run the program it is giving me the same sum for say the name "lala" and "francis".  If anybody could help me see what is wrong with the code, it will be greatly appreciated!

LinkedListNode class: (contains the getSum method)

```
public class LinkedListNode 
{ 

    public String data; 
    public LinkedListNode next; 
   public long sum; 


    public LinkedListNode(String data)  
   { 
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = null; 
        this.sum = getSum(data); 
    }//end node 

   public long getSum(String line) 
    { 
        int i; 
        long sum = 0; 
        String s = null; 
      char a; 

           for(i=0; i < 3; i++) 
         { 
            int j = 2; 
            a = line.charAt(i);      
            sum += Character.getNumericValue(a) * Math.pow(26, j); 
            //Return the value of the number 4 to be the power of 3 (4*4*4): Math.pow(4,3); 
            j--; 
           }//end for  

        return sum; 
    }//end getSum 

    public long getSum() 
    { 
      return sum; 
    }//end getSum 

    public String getData()  
   { 
        return data; 
    }//end getData 
    public void setData(String data)  
   { 
        this.data = data; 
    }//end setData 
    public LinkedListNode getNext()  
   { 
        return next; 
    }//end node 
    public void setNext(LinkedListNode next)  
   { 
        this.next = next; 
    }//end setNext 

}//end class node
```

LinkedList class: (has other methods for the list)

```
public class LinkedList { 

    public LinkedListNode front; 

    public LinkedList() { 
        this.front = null; 
    } 

    public void insertBack(String data) 
   { 
        if(front == null){ 
            front = new LinkedListNode(data); 
        }else{ 
            LinkedListNode newNode = new LinkedListNode(data); 
            LinkedListNode current = front; 
            while(current.getNext() != null){ 
                current = current.getNext(); 
            } 
            current.setNext(newNode); 
        }        
    }//end insertBack 

   public void addAfter(LinkedListNode spot, String data) 
   { 
       LinkedListNode newNode; 

       newNode = new LinkedListNode(data); 

       newNode.next = spot.next; 
       spot.next = newNode; 
   }//end addAfter 

   public void addBefore(LinkedListNode spot, String data) 
   { 

   }//end addBefore    

   public void deleteAfter(LinkedListNode spot) 
   { 
       LinkedListNode nextNode; 

       nextNode = spot.next; 
       spot.next = nextNode.next; 
   }//end deleteAfter 


    public String showList() 
   { 
        int i = 0; 
        String retStr = "The nodes in the list are:\n"; 
        LinkedListNode current = front; 
        while(current != null){ 
            i++; 
            retStr += "Node " + i + " is: " + current.getData() + " and the sum is: " + current.getSum() + "\n"; 
            current = current.getNext(); 

        } 

        return retStr; 
    } 

   public LinkedListNode findTail() 
   { 
       LinkedListNode current = front; 
        while(current.getNext() != null) 
      { 
            current = current.getNext(); 
        } 
      return current; 
   }//end findTail 
}
```

fileIn class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*; 

public class fileIn 
{ 
   LinkedListNode front; 
   LinkedList myList = new LinkedList(); 
   String fname; 

   public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
       fileIn f = new fileIn(); 
   }//end main 


   public fileIn() 
   { 
      getFileName(); 
      readFileContents(); 
      System.out.print(myList.showList()); 
   }//end namesLinkedList 

   public void readFileContents() 
    { 
        boolean looping; 
        DataInputStream in; 
        String line; 
        int j, len; 
        char ch; 

        /* Read input from file and process. */
        try 
        { 
            in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(fname)); 

            looping = true; 
            while(looping) 
             { 
                /* Get a line of input from the file. */
                if (null == (line = in.readLine()))  
                { 
                    looping = false; 
                    /* Close and free up system resource. */
                    in.close(); 
                }//end if 
                else 
                { 
                myList.insertBack(line); 
                    j = 0; 
                    len = line.length();   
                }//end else 
            } /* End while. */

        } /* End try. */

        catch(IOException e)  
        { 
            System.out.println("Error " + e); 
        } /* End catch. */
    }//end readFileContents 

     public void getFileName() 
     { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println("Enter file name please."); 
        fname = in.nextLine(); 

     }//end getFileName 

}//end class namesLinkedList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    int j = 2; 
    a = line.charAt(i);      
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(a) * Math.pow(26, j); 
    j--; 
}
```

You're getting the same result because the exponent is always `2`. This leads to the same value for `fra` ([15×26<sup>2</sup> + 27×26<sup>2</sup> + 10×26<sup>2</sup> = 35,152](https://www.google.com/search?q=15%2a26%2a%2a2+%2B+27%2a26%2a%2a2+%2B+10%2a26%2a%2a2)) and `lal` ([21×26<sup>2</sup> + 10×26<sup>2</sup> + 21×26<sup>2</sup> = 35,152](https://www.google.com/search?q=21%2a26%2a%2a2+%2B+10%2a26%2a%2a2+%2B+21%2a26%2a%2a2)). Why is this?

The variable `j` is declared inside the loop instead of outside. The decrement at the end has no effect since it starts over at `2` at the beginning of each iteration.

You should move the declaration out of the loop:

```
int j = 2; 

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    a = line.charAt(i);      
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(a) * Math.pow(26, j); 
    j--; 
}
```

Or you could replace `j` with `2 - i` and get rid of the extra variable entirely.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
    a = line.charAt(i);      
    sum += Character.getNumericValue(a) * Math.pow(26, 2 - i); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect sir, sometimes it just takes another set of eyes lol.  I like how you were able to void j out entirely.

Comment: Haha I was curious, me and a buddy were working through that in so many ways and kept getting the wrong answer.

Comment: @JohnKugelman A minor correction: "fra" is `15 27 10` and "lal" is `21 10 21`, not `102 114 97` and `108 97 108`. The reason they were equivalent is still the same (`'f' = 'l' - 6` and `'r' = 'l' + 6`) but the OP is using `Character.getNumericValue()` which returns 10-31 for a-z, not the character code.

Comment: @Shawn To ensure uniqueness (and stick to your specification), you probably want to either subtract 10 from the result of `getNumericValue()`, or multiply by 32^N. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char). You should also accept John's answer. :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman The man answered it so fast it made me wait to mark his answer ;)

Comment: (I meant 36^N not 32^N and 10-35 not 10-31, and my sincerest apologies to the 4 letters I was willing to sacrifice to construct the weird 22-character alphabet that was in my head).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your math is wrong. Character.getNumericValue(a) will not return you a value between 0 and 25 like you seem to think. 
Just make a custom Comparator class if you want to sort based on fist 3 letters and use that.

Edit: I was wrong about how getNumericValue works, but the math is still wrong (see comment below).

Comment: You are correct in that `getNumericValue()` does not return 0-25, but it does not return a Unicode code point either. It returns 10-31 for a-z, case-insensitive, and is intended to convert digits to integers (taking intended value into account, e.g. \u216C [roman numeral 50] returns 50). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char).

Comment: @JasonC yes, my bad. But the issue still stands - even if the max value in this case is 35, pow(26, ...) will not work, it needs to be pow(36,...) or the initial value should be shifted so 'a' becomes zero in case those words cannot have numbers in them.